# Keyboard not working after pressing windows button

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, logitech-keyboard

**Keyboard not working after pressing windows button**

1. **The problem**: for an unknown reason to me, my keyboard stops working after pressing the windows button. The windows start menu appears after pressing the button but then most keys stop working, that means, no searching, can't close the menu with esc key, can't navigate the menu with tab and arrow keys, etc. So far the only two known key combos that work, or at least that I found are, ctrl+shit+esc for task manager, ctrl+alt+del for the switch user menu, win+x, and win+r.
2. **Things I tried:**

- Restaring pc
- Replugging keyboard
- Reinstalling device from device manager
- Updating drivers from device manager
- Turning off Sticky Keys (easy of access)
- Turning off Filter Keys (easy of access)
- Ran Malwarebytes (found nothing)
- Bought new keyboard
- Ran Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- Ran sfc /scannow

3. **Specs that may help:**

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19045)
- Keyboard: Logitech K120
- New Keyboard: Logitech K850

**Thank you**

Comment: You need perhaps a new keyboard.

Comment: 1. Alt-Tab should clear the Star-Menu-Taskbar popup. Try selecting the current app. 2. If that doesn't work, try testing with another keyboard to see if it's a hardware issue. 3. Try using DISM and SFC to check system files.

Comment: @harrymc I just bought a new keyboard. Same issue.

Comment: Is the new keyboard same as the old? Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc No its a different model. I tried both your suggestions, neither worked.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?